# Integrate react into existing html admin panel

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an admin application. Downloaded a good bootstrap based admin panel template from themeforest. But then had a thought about making the application in react. But I am very new to react and just playing with hello world.

So my question is, is it possible to integrate react into existing bootstrap admin template? I have heard react can work as just a library.

Please share your suggestion or challenges if I would like to proceed with that way

Comment: Refer to this [Adding React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)

Comment: @teja463 Thanks a lot. So in your opinion, will there be any serious challenge if I go with react library on my existing bootstrap admin template ?